# What is the problems about java number++?

Tags: java

i have tried this ,found the questions

```
public class Baz {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int num = 5;
        for(int i=0 ;i < 4 ; i++) {
          num = num++;
        }
       System.out.println("Value is :" + num);
    }
}
```

the result print Values is 5, What happen ?

Answer (score 2):

```
num = num++;
```

is the same as

```
num = num;
```

because the numerical value of the expression `num++` is the value of `num` *before* it is incremented; so although `num++` has the side-effect of incrementing `num`, it is immediately reverted by the assignment,

As such, the value of `num` is left unchanged.

Answer (score 2):

```
num = num++;   // don't do this
```

`num++` increments the variable, but it first evaluates to the current value, which is then assigned to the variable by `num =`. The incremented value is just discarded.

In other languages (such as C), this is even undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

num++ is the same as num = num +1

So you should just do as follows:

```
public class Baz {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int num = 5;
    for(int i=0 ;i < 4 ; i++) {
       num++;
    }
   System.out.println("Value is :" + num);
}
```

}

Comment: No: `num = num++` is the same as `num = num`.

Comment: Yes, and num++ is the same as num = num +1, that's what I said

Comment: No: the value assigned to by this expression is the value of `num` before it is incremented, *not* after. That is the difference between post- and pre-incrementing.

Comment: `num++` is not the same as `num = num + 1`.  If one changes the code to `num = ( num = num + 1 )` it does not stay at 5.

Comment: Right, that's why i said to modify the line as in the answer, which is the same as :

for(int i=0 ;i < 4 ; i++) {
       num = num +1;
    }

Answer (score 0):

The line `num = num++` makes no sense. `num++` is equal to `num = num + 1`

So you have to change your code into:

```
public class Baz {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int num = 5;
        for(int i=0 ;i < 4 ; i++) {
          num++;
        }
       System.out.println("Value is :" + num);
    }
}
```